# How to place a text next to an image?

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to place the text that's currently below the picture next to the image but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried a bunch of things but it screwed it up. I'm pretty sure this is an easy fix but I'm a noob. :D

http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/5/

**HTML**

```
    <li class="post" >
        <article class="in-column" style="height:300px;"> <a href="http://yahoo.com"> <p class="article-title" style="font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px;">Grumpy Cat</p><img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0"; height="200" width="300"></a>
        <p class="excerpt" style="float:left;">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism. <a href="http://yahoo.com"><b>[READ MORE]</b></p></a>
        <p class="excerpt">Born: April 4, 2012, Morristown, AZ</p>
      </article>
      </li>

      </section>
      </section>
```

**CSS**

```
 article.in-column {    
     border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left: 25px;
     padding-right: 25px;   
     padding-top: 15px; 

 }

 article.in-column .excerpt {
     color: #2f2f2f;
     font-size: 11px;
     margin: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;   

 }

 p.article-title{
         line-height: 19px;
     margin: 5px 0px;
     color: #151515;
     font-weight:bold;
         font-size:16px;
 }
```

Comment: Where exactly because I already have it and it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `style="float:left;"` on your **image**, not on your text.

Also, remove the stray semicolon in your `img` tag.

As shown here:

```
<img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0"; height="200" width="300">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/7/)

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes because it's not letting me now. May I ask why do I need to remove the img tag? Is it a good idea to use it or not?

Comment: No no no, don't remove the `img` tag, just the semicolon after the border-attribute!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
 <ul style="list-style:none; width:700px">
     <li style="float:left; margin:5px;width:310px;">
         <ul style="list-style:none">
             <li>
                  <span  style="font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px;">Grumpy Cat</span>
             </li>
             <li>
                  <a href="http://yahoo.com" style="float:left;margin-right:5px">
```

```
     </li>
     <li style="float:left;width:380px;">
         <ul style="list-style:none">
             <li>
                  <span style="font-weight:700" >Born: April 4, 2012, Morristown, AZ</span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism. <a href="http://yahoo.com"><b>[READ MORE]</b></a>
             </li>
         </ul>




     </li>
 </ul>



      see http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/15/
```